# Multiple fixed value validation in XML using XSD

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd

I have following XML element which may hold "red" or "blue" value.

```
<color>red</color>
<color>blue</color>
```

I need to validate the xml whether it is having only red or blue.
How to check multiple fixed values in xsd ?

**Current XSD:**

```
<xs:element name="color" type="xs:string" fixed="red"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<xs:element name="color" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="blue"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>                   
            </xs:element>
```